# After ajax post, appended div not displaying in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, internet-explorer, dom

I'm posting data to my webserver and returning a success or fail status. I'd like to display a confirmation or error message to the user after the ajax post. It works as expected in Chrome and IE 9, but IE 8 will not display the newly appended `div` that is my confirmation message.

Using IE 8's DOM inspector, I found that the div element is in fact being appended to the DOM, but is just not being displayed. Perhaps IE isn't getting some sort of screen refresh event after I append the element? I am appending DOM elements in ajax callback functions in other places in my code, using `$.getJSON()` -- it seems that IE is seeing the POST method and deciding to not let me update the DOM.

My ajax code looks like this:

```
$.post("adminpage.ashx?action=newAccount", newData, function (response) {
      getAccount(newData.accountNum);   // display the new account
      if (response == "success") {
          createAlert("Account was successfully updated.", "success").appendTo(".container");
      } else if (response == "error") {
          createAlert("There was an error updating the account.", "error").appendTo(".container");
      }
});
```

`createAlert()` returns the div with my confirmation or error message.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the code for my createAlert function:

```
function createAlert(message, type) {
    var alert = $("<div>");
    alert.addClass("alert alert-block");
    if (typeof type != "undefined") {
        alert.addClass("alert-" + type);
    }

    var dismissButton = $("<button>");
    dismissButton.addClass("close").attr("data-dismiss", "alert").text("x");
    dismissButton.appendTo(alert);

    var alertText = $("<p>");
    alertText.text(message);

    alert.append(message);

    return alert;
}
```

And the HTML that IE 8's debugger shows:

```
<DIV class="alert alert-block alert-success">
    <BUTTON class=close type=submit data-dismiss="alert">x</BUTTON>Account was successfully updated.
</DIV>
```

Comment: sounds like a CSS problem to me, can we see the html generated by `createAlert("test", "success")`?

Comment: I agree with @KevinB, but it could also be an HTML issue. IE 8 is actually far stricter about sticking to the HTML standard than any other browser (even IE 9). So you can't, for instance, put a ``<form>`` inside of another ``<form>``, and you can't put a ``<div>`` inside of a ``<span>``, etc. What's the tag of this ``.container``?

Comment: @KevinB @David I've added the code to my question. The container is a `<div>` and its parent is the `<body>` The alert does curiously show up later on if I start typing in my autocomplete box. It seems to me like the appending of the autocomplete box to the DOM triggers the screen refresh necessary that wasn't being triggered after the AJAX post.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue but I finally got it to work by using a variant function so instead of writing

```
  someObj.appendTo('.blabla');
```

I wrote

```
 $('.blabla').append(someObj);
```

If you're tempted to try

```
$.post("adminpage.ashx?action=newAccount", newData, function (response) {
  getAccount(newData.accountNum);   // display the new account
  if (response == "success") {
      $(".container").append(createAlert("Account was successfully updated.", "success"));
  } else if (response == "error") {
      $(".container").append(createAlert("There was an error updating the account.", "error"));
  }
});
```